# Is there any 8-bit single byte character encoding, that includes russian (cyrillic) and german chars? (usage: fpdf)

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, fpdf

I am working on a **project based on fpdf** and got in trouble by using special chars.
I know that fpdf is not supporting any utf8 and that I have to build my own font to use special chars.
This is already working for **russian chars** by using the iso-8859-5 encoding and also for **german characters** with a few other encodings.

**But is it right, that there is no encoding I can use, that supports both?**

In addition to that:
It's a quite old and big project that is already using fpdf. I know that there are other versions like mpdf and so on, that can handle utf8, but if there is any other solution than replacing the whole system, I would really like to do that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such single encoding.

The closest I found is CP771, which supports both Lithuanian and Russian, but first: it doesn't solve your problem, second: it won't be supported by anything anyway.

You can define separate fonts for both languages, I think that would be the easiest way.

Following the tutorial at http://fpdf.de/tutorials/7/ I guess this would work:

```
MakeFont('comic.ttf','comicDE.afm','cp1252');
MakeFont('comic.ttf','comicRU.afm','iso-8859-5');
```

and then:

```
$pdf->AddFont('ComicDE','','comicDE.php');
$pdf->AddFont('ComicRU','','comicRU.php');
```

Of course this requires you to encode text and add it to the PDF in different ways depending on the language it is in, but I think that's the limitation of the library that would be hard to overcome in a different way anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am afraid you are right and there is no better solution than using different font files. Quite a bad one, because we are using both languages in one file so we need to separate nearly each word, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I've extended FPDF like this and it seems to handle UTF8 input pretty well:

```
class PDF extends FPDF {

    function Cell( $w, $h = 0, $t = '', $b = 0, $l = 0, $a = '', $f = false, $y = '' ) {

        parent::Cell( $w, $h, iconv( 'UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $t ), $b, $l, $a, $f, $y );

    }

}
```